# Red Hat AMQ 7.1 broker- JMSSecurityException

Tags: activemq-artemis

> javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ119213: User: epic does not have permission='CONSUME' for queue service_input on address service_input.service_input

In broker.xml have given the permission to user epic but still issue not resolved

```
<security-settings>
     <security-setting match="#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq, epic, guest"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq,epic, guest"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq, epic, guest"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq, epic , guest"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="amq, epic , guest"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="amq, epic , guest"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="amq, epic , guest"/>
        <permission type="manage" roles="amq, epic , guest"/>
     </security-setting>
     </security-settings>
       <address-settings>
         <address-setting match="epic.#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>

    </address-settings>
        <addresses>
        <address name="epic.PipelineEngine">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="execute_exchange" />
               <queue name="service_exchange" />
               <queue name="input_exchange" />
               <queue name="unknown_exchange" />
               <queue name="control_message_exchange" />
               <queue name="notification_exchange" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
  </addresses>
```

Comment: Can you put your broker.xml in the question? Also, it would be great to see your client code as well. It's impossible to answer your question with the details you've provided.

Comment: Hi Justin i have added broker.xml please check

Comment: Can you also add your bootstrap.xml, login.config, and the user & roles properties files (assuming you use the `PropertiesLoginModule`)?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Hi Justin its working fine now.. it was some installation problem I have reinstalled the broker.. it worked!! Thank you

Comment: You should answer your own (i.e. this) question with an explanation of the solution so that people who have this problem in the future can benefit from your experience.